# Is $\Bbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2)$ a UFD or Noetherian?

Tags: abstract-algebra, noetherian, unique-factorization-domains

Hello everyone I would like to know if

> $R$:= $\Bbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2)$ is UFD or Noetherian.

I'm not really confortable in seeing how $\Bbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2)$ looks like. From what i've understood this is the set of all the equivalence classes

$$[p]\quad s.t \quad [p] = p + (X^2+Y^2)$$

Where $p \in \Bbb{R}[X,Y]$ is a polynomial in two variables and $(X^2+Y^2)$ is the ideal generated by the polynomial $X^2+Y^2$ that is $\{r\,(X^2+Y^2)\,|\,r\in R \}$. Is this correct? What are the element $r \in R$ that helps generating the ideal? Are they maybe elements of $\Bbb{R}[X,Y]$? Sorry if my questions sound stupid, but i'm really confused and it will be great if you help me figure this out.

I also tried to show that $R$ is not a UFD. I've thought that  if it was, then every element should have had a factorization into irreducible elements of $\Bbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2)$ but if I take the equivalence class $[0]=(X^2+Y^2)$ i see that it cannot be found any factorization of $X^2+Y^2$ since this polynomial is irreducible in $\Bbb{R}[X,Y]$. Is it correct?

Also to show that $R$ is Noetherian or not i was thinking to show that in $R$ every ideal is finitely generated or that there is an ideal which is not finitely generated, but i don't know how the ideals of $R$ look like, could please help me? Thank you in advance

Comment: A quotient of a polynomial ring in finite # variables and ring of coefficients noetherian is noetherian. Check Hilbert basis theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem

Comment: @orangeskid thank you for your comment. Unfortunately i've started the algebra course 2 weeks ago and i can't really see how the Hilbert's basis theorem will help me to say that $R$ is Noetherian, could you please elaborate?

Comment: @Ale The HBT (after two applications) says $\Bbb R[X,Y]=R[X][Y]$ is Noetherian. Since the quotient of a Noetherian ring is Noetherian, you'd be done.

Comment: @rschwieb Ok thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of thinking about this is to say that factoring out by the ideal is equivalent to setting $X^2+Y^2=0$ in the original ring. Hence $Y^2=-X^2$ and one can find a form of each element (coset representative) where $Y$ does not appear to any power higher than $1$, which is the same as saying the elements of the factor ring can be taken to be of the form $p(X)+q(X)Y$ where $p, q$ are arbitrary polynomials with real coefficients.

Can you see here a factorisation which is not unique?

---

If you have a polynomial like $X^2+3X+2+5XY^5+2X^3Y^2+20Y$ you have $5XY^3(X^2+Y^2)=0$ in the factor ring, so that $5XY^5=-5X^3Y^3$, and we have reduced the exponent of $Y$ by $2$. We can do the same trick again to give us $5XY^5=-5X^3Y^3=5X^5Y$.

Term by term we can reduce the exponent of $Y$ to $0$ or $1$.

Look carefully at $Y^2=-X^2$.

Comment: +1 Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately i did not completely understand why one can reduce the ring $R=\Bbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2)$ to a ring where the elements have the form $q(X)+p(X)Y$, with $p,q$ polynomial with real coeffiecients. Also i tried to find a factorization which was not unique, but I think I did not success. Do I have to treat $Y$ as a constant or as a variable? If i have to treat it like a constant the i would choose $p(X) = X^2$ and $q(X)=1$, in such a way that $X^2 + Y$ is not reducible, is it correct?

Comment: I've added some comments in the answer.

Comment: Wow! Thank you, now is a little bit clearer for me how to handle this factor rings! I've taken as polynomial with two different factorizations $X^2-36Y^2$, indeed this is equal $(X-6Y)(X+6Y)$ and also equal $X^2 + 36X^2 =37X^2 = 37\cdot X \cdot X$, which are two irreducible factorizations, is that right?

Comment: @Ale:  That works.  But it would be simpler to write $X\cdot X=-Y\cdot Y$.

Comment: @WillO Ok, thank you for confirming me that ;D I think clever answer comes with the experience eheh i need to practice a little bit more! Have a nice evening you both and thank you for having helped me!