# Is $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/(x^2+y)$ a UFD?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

I guess if we find two factorisations which are the same then we could say that it is not a UFD.
I saw the related question [Is $\Bbb{R}[X,Y]/(X^2+Y^2)$ a UFD or Noetherian?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/952777/is-bbbrx-y-x2y2-a-ufd-or-noetherian?noredirect=1&lq=1) and I tried following the same example.

The thing I don't understand is why we can reduce it to $x^2+y=0$.

And could somebody give me a hint regarding the factorisation. I couldn't find any since the fact that y has degree 1 makes it hard but I am not sure at all.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It is just a relation such that $y=-x^2$, so your ring is $\mathbb C[x,-x^2]=\mathbb C[x]$.

Comment: "*I guess if we find two factorisations which are the same then we could say that it is not a UFD.*" This is a misconception often encountered. In $\mathbb Z$ we can write $2\cdot 6=3\cdot 4$. Does this mean that $\mathbb Z$ is not a UFD?

Comment: @user26857 you are right, I guess the factors should also be irreducible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let's note that $\mathbb{C}[x, y] / (x^2 + y) \cong \mathbb{C}[x]$ under the mapping sending $x$ to $x$ and $y$ to $-x^2$.

Since $\mathbb{C}$ is a field, $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a Euclidean domain, hence a UFD.

And of course being a UFD is a property which is invariant under ring isomorphism.